# Mobile Safari Fixed Position Footer Problems

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari, positioning, css-position, sticky-footer

How do you get a mobile safari fixed position footer to stay where it belongs and not bounce?

Comment: what's the code your having already ?

Comment: @Ivo Jonkers He has already answered his own question. I think OP just want to share his discovery about this scope when ask and answer within minute :P

Comment: Yes...I was just blown away by how well it worked, and wanted to share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright - I solved this one before going crazy.  I don't know if it will work in all situations, but it works like a charm on my iPhone 4s.

Assuming you have the proper css, which is something like:

```
body { 
    height:100%;
}

#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

and you have set the viewport for mobile devices -

This solution worked perfectly for me.  I am using jQuery, but not jQueryMobile.  This small bit of javascript/jq code solved everything, and there is no bouncing or other visual gaffes:

```
document.ontouchstart=function(){
    $('#footer').animate({bottom:0},1);
}
```

And that's it!  Hope this is helpful to someone.